# What Animal is This Skin From? A Wooly Mammoth?

Tags: zoology, skin

I was at the American Museum of Natural History in New York City today, and I saw the skin pictured below. Because it was next to stuff about wooly mammoths, I thought it might be a mammoth skin. However, there was no sign accompanying the skin. What is it from?

[image]

Comment: its looks like an elephant's leg on the right. close enough to be a mammoth then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the remains of a wooly mammoth. Many mammoths have been found frozen and well preserved in Siberia.